# How to jump to the beginning or end of line in vim + OS X

Tags: macos, mac, vim

In terminal I can do this by pressing shift+home and shift+end, but it doesn't seem to work in vim. Home and end keys scroll terminal window only. I would like to jump in edit mode.

Comment: In command mode, you can find on the Vim Cheat Sheet (0 and $): http://www.fprintf.net/vimCheatSheet.html. I don't know about edit mode, though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This answer assumes you are using *vim* in a *Terminal* window.

The default bindings for **Home** and **End** are a bit different from what a program would expect based on the usual TERM setting (i.e. an xterm variant). If you want to stick with the default bindings (and having to use the Shifted variants in *Terminal*), you might try putting something like this in your `.vimrc`:

```
:" map Mac OS X Terminal.app default Home and End
:map <ESC>[H <Home>
:map <ESC>[F <End>
:imap <ESC>[H <C-O><Home>
:imap <ESC>[F <C-O><End>
:cmap <ESC>[H <Home>
:cmap <ESC>[F <End>
```

Otherwise, you might try adjusting the codes that *Terminal* sends when you use **Home** and **End** (unshifted even, if you like). A search would probably turn up some places that describe how to do it ([here is one](http://keith.chaos-realm.net/archives/198-OSX-Terminal-Home-End-Keys.html)). The basic idea is that you want to have Terminal send *ESC*[1~ instead of *ESC*[H for **Home** and *ESC*[4~ instead of *ESC*[F for **End** (or Shift-Home/Shift-End if you want to keep Home/End for accessing scrollback). I would describe the process in more detail, but I only have 10.4, and I know Terminal was changed a lot in 10.5 and later.

Answer (score 15):

With iTerm and Vim you can use **fn+right and left arrows** in insert mode to jump to begin or end of line. With Terminal.app you use **shift+arrows**.

Comment: Hey, just got a 2020 macbook and those shortcuts are no longer working in iterm+vim (instead it scrolls one lilne down/up) any ideas ?

Answer (score 11):

use 0 and $ to move to beginning and end of line. Refer this site : http://alvinalexander.com/linux/vi-vim-editor-end-of-line.

Comment: The OP wants to jump in editing mode, not in command mode, so these keys will just literally input `0` and `$`.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to [Chris answer](https://superuser.com/a/123958/282311), you may also achieve word navigation (with `Option+arrow` keys), just by adding those four lines:

```
:map <ESC>f el
:imap <ESC>b <C-o>b
:imap <ESC>f <C-o>el
:cmap <ESC>f el
```

Notice the `o` is lower case, so that it won't exit `insert` mode for the operation. You can also change the uppercase `O` in the original answer for the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Terminal -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Keyboard and add:

Key: ↖ Action: \033OH

Key: ↗ Action: \033OF

Answer (score 1):

As of Nov'23, these simple shortcuts work for me with vim (insert mode) open in Terminal app. This works OOTB, no editing of rc files etc. is needed.

`Shift+left/right` - move word by word

`Fn+Shift+left/right` - jump to beginning or end of the line

`Fn+Shift+up/down` - page up/page down

Answer (score 0):

In MacVim, you can use Command 'Left Arrow' and Command 'Right Arrow' to go to the beginning and end of line while being in edit mode.

Comment: Sounds like JtR is using vim inside Terminal.app instead of using MacVim (which I would highly recommend, and personally use, as well).